# Question about passing sapply index to function

Tags: r, function, loops, sapply

I am sure this is a simple problem. But I am new to programming so I am struggling. I think what I am trying to accomplish should be pretty clear from the code. Essentially, I want to generate a vector of random numbers of length i, check if there is less than i unique numbers. And I want to do this a bunch of times as a sort of simulation. When I do it i by i manually using the following code:

```
experiment<- function() {
          ab <- rdunif(i, 1, 365)
          ab <- data.frame(ab)
          count <- uniqueN(ab)
          if (count < i)
            return(1)
          else
            return(0)
        }
                
        vector <- replicate(10, experiment(), simplify=FALSE)
        sum <- sum(as.data.frame((vector)))
        probability <- sum/(10)
```

It works fine. But I need to run this simulation 40 times and I would rather not do it by hand. However, I can't seem to get sapply to work for me and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong:

```
i<-10:50
    experiment<- function(i) {
      ab <- rdunif(i, 1, 365)
      ab <- data.frame(ab)
      count <- uniqueN(ab)
      if (count < i)
        return(1)
      else
        return(0)
    }
    
    complete <- function(i) {
    
    vector <- replicate(10, experiment(i), simplify=FALSE)
    sum <- sum(as.data.frame((vector)))
    probability <- sum/(10)
    
    return(probability)
    }
    
    sapply(i, complete(i), simplify=FALSE)
```

This is the error I am currently experiencing:
Error in match.fun(FUN) :
'complete(i)' is not a function, character or symbol
In addition: Warning messages:

```
1: In if (count < i) return(1) else return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (count < i) return(1) else return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (count < i) return(1) else return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (count < i) return(1) else return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (count < i) return(1) else return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In if (count < i) return(1) else return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
7: In if (count < i) return(1) else return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
8: In if (count < i) return(1) else return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
9: In if (count < i) return(1) else return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
10: In if (count < i) return(1) else return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Not sure what the function uniqueN is, but the rest of this looks like R. The R unique function returns a vector, not a scalar (the unique values). So the error is just telling you that the return value of experiment() is being selected from the first value of the count array (b/c what else would it do?). Replace 
count <- uniqueN(ab) with 
count <- length(unique(ab))
Also, the data.frame step is not doing anything useful.

Comment: when using `sapply()`, its `FUN` argument is just the function name, i.e. you need to call it like `sapply(i, complete, simplify=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
    experiment<- function(i) {
  ab <- rdunif(i, 1, 365)
  count <- length(unique(ab))
  if (count < i) return(1)
  else return(0)
}

i <- 10:50

replication <- function(i) {
  replicate(100, experiment(i))
}

data<- sapply(i, replication)

colMeans(data)
```